# Semantic Logging: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: logging, event-listener, etw

Im trying to use new semantic application block for logging. As per MSDN i have test method which inspects the EventSource using

```
EventSourceAnalyzer.InspectAll(MyEventSource.Log);
```

But when i run this test i'm getting error

```
An item with the same key has already been added
```

Usually we get this error if we use same event id, but im using different EventID for each method. Below is my event source class

```
EventSource(Name = "SLAB_1.1.1403.1")]
public class MyEventSource : EventSource
{
    public class Keywords
    {
        public const EventKeywords Page = (EventKeywords)1;
        public const EventKeywords DataBase = (EventKeywords)2;
        public const EventKeywords Diagnostic = (EventKeywords)4;
        public const EventKeywords Perf = (EventKeywords)8;
    }

    public class Tasks
    {
        public const EventTask Page = (EventTask)1;
        public const EventTask DBQuery = (EventTask)2;
    }

    private static MyEventSource _log = new MyEventSource();
    private MyEventSource() { }
    public static MyEventSource Log { get { return _log; } }

    [Event(1, Message = "Application Failure: {0}",
    Level = EventLevel.Critical, Keywords = Keywords.Diagnostic)]
    internal void Failure(string message)
    {
        if (this.IsEnabled(EventLevel.Critical, Keywords.Diagnostic))
        {
            this.WriteEvent(1, message);
        }
    }

    [Event(2, Message = "Application Failure1: {0}",
    Level = EventLevel.Critical, Keywords = Keywords.Diagnostic)]
    internal void Failure(string message, string exception)
    {
        if (this.IsEnabled(EventLevel.Critical, Keywords.Diagnostic))
        {
            this.WriteEvent(2, message, exception);
        }
    }

    [NonEvent]
    internal void Failure(string message, Exception ex)
    {
        if (this.IsEnabled(EventLevel.Critical, Keywords.Diagnostic))
        {
            Failure(message, ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The method name is the key, so since you have two methods named Failure, even though you have different parameter lists, the SLAB infrastructure is adding the method name as a key to a dictionary. Rename one of your Failure methods to Failure2 or something like that to fix this problem.